# How to prevent local host name resolving from DHCP names in OpenWRT/dnsmasq

Tags: dnsmasq, openwrt

I have OpenWRT 14.07 running on my home router. It has DNS and DHCP services enabled for the local LAN devices.

However, this also "leaks" the name of each device connected to the router, even if connected to the same router through a [different LAN](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/recipes/guest-wlan-webinterface). The entire network is like this:

```
OpenWRT router @ 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.222.1
 |-- LAN
 |    '-- DesktopComputer @ 192.168.0.99
 '-- Guest LAN
      '-- LaptopComputer @ 192.168.222.88
```

Running any of the following commands on LaptopComputer:

```
$ dig  -x  192.168.0.99 @192.168.0.1
$ nslookup 192.168.0.99  192.168.0.1
```

Returns `LaptopComputer.lan.` as the result.

**This means `dnsmasq` in OpenWRT is resolving internal IP addresses to internal names based on the names from DHCP negotiation. How can I prevent that?**

I want such reverse-resolutions to simply fail (or return `NXDOMAIN`, or whatever is the appropriate response).

I don't even use local host name resolution, so I'm also accepting a solution that disables it entirely (while still resolving Internet names).

Comment: What I do in a similar situation (no openwrt, but dd-wrt) is add this option top dnsmasq: dhcp-option=br1,6,8.8.8.8 , where br1 is the guest vlan interface, option 6 is the dns server option en 8.8.8.8 is one of google's dns servers. So guests never get to query the internal lan

Comment: You understand that the purpose of DNS is to provide name resolution, right? The DNS server/service on the router isn't "leaking" the names. It's resolving the names, as it's intended to. Have you read the documentation for dnsmasq on OpenWRT? You'll probably find your solution there.

Comment: @joeqwerty: Yes, I understand the purpose. Yes, I read [OpenWRT wiki](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/dhcp) and [dnsmasq manpage](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html). The closest option I found was `boguspriv`, but it still looks in `/etc/hosts` and DHCP leases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your option of choice for *dnsmasq* appears to be:

> *--dhcp-ignore-names[=tag:[,tag:]]* - Ignore hostnames provided by DHCP clients.
>
> When all the given tags appear in the tag
>   set, ignore any hostname provided by the host. Note that, unlike
>   dhcp-ignore, it is permissible to supply no  tags, in which case
>   DHCP-client supplied hostnames are always ignored, and DHCP hosts are
>   added to the DNS using only dhcp-host configuration in dnsmasq and the
>   contents of /etc/hosts and /etc/ethers.

This option is available in dnsmasq 2.71, which is part of OpenWrt Barrier Breaker 14.07.

If you don't specify any hosts in */etc/hosts* or */etc/ethers* (or disable using them completely) no hostname information should "leak" anymore. However, be aware that thare're other tools like ie. Netscan, nbtscan, or the whole lots of Metasploit scanners, that can provide this information if not firewalled tightly.

Comment: Great idea! Unfortunately, it did not work. I tried adding `dhcp-ignore-names` to `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`, but the behavior remained the same. I've even tried editing `/etc/init.d/dnsmasq` to add `--dhcp-ignore-names` parameter, and checked using `ps` that it was used, but still no change in the behavior. (Of course, restarting with `/etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart`.)

Comment: Have you "cleaned" the *dhcp-leasefile* (default: */tmp/dhcp.leases*)? I also use Barrier Breaker for my home network, and *dhcp-ignore-names* option works as expected for me, but I had to remove the old lease entries or replace host names with asterisks and only then restart. It should also help to wait for the leases to expire.

Comment: Okay, it works. However, dnsmasq will still resolve names if you have defined them in *Static Leases*. It happens because, behind-the-scenes, this option will write `*` to the DHCP leases; and dnsmasq will always use the leases when resolving names.